# Encode image base64

Tags: css, image, base64

I have tried to base encode my image to show it via CSS as:

```
background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,%codeForImage%)
```

So I tried what I found here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/Base64_encoding_and_decoding

But it won't show me any image (using the png image from 'phonegap android drawable'.

Two questions:

How can I solve this or
how can I show an image without base64 it before.

Example: Is it possible to grab the bytes of an image and show it via

```
background-image:url(data:%uncodedImageBytes%)
```

Background:
I am getting the bytes of an image from a phonegap plugin and I am trying to show the image to the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend against Base 64 for mobile applications in general.

**[Why?  Check here.](http://www.mobify.com/blog/css-sprites-vs-data-uris-which-is-faster-on-mobile/)**

If you want to use Base64 despite the performance increase, then I recommend using a site like [this one](http://webcodertools.com/imagetobase64converter) in order to do your Base64 encoding.  Otherwise, your url string looks appropriate, but binary isn't the format it's expecting.  Funny enough, it's expecting Base64 - which is something different entirely.

**Edit**

If you need to do this at runtime and only with binaries, do it in JavaScript.  It has a function baked in which will handle encoding Base64 from binary hanging from the Window object.

[Here's the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64.btoa)

**Use it like this:**

```
var bSixtyFourString = window.btoa(%MY_BINARY%);
```

Comment: Thanks, I did not ask for speed, but how to manage to show the image. I do have the binary data at runtime, so that I cannot call upon a site. How can I do the base encoding on the binaries?

Comment: in my post in line 4. That is btoa(). But it gives me an unicode problem (again as described in the link). That's where my questions starts. The workarounds do not help me, as it seems that the image gets corrupted by these).

Comment: @protobassi - Corrupted how?  Have you verified that you're getting binary back and not a byte string?  You can convert to binary via JavaScript again if it is in bytes and not bits, but you're going through a _LOT_ of hoops just to deliver an image at that point and you're probably better just delivering it with the app in a raw state.

Answer (score 2):

The first piece of code is correct:

```
background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,%codeForImage%)
```

Inserting binary data won't work.

If you see a different image instead of the one you're expecting, then either your CSS selectors don't match the element (for example if the element is a `<div id="foobar">`, and your selector is `div.foobar`), or your selector is [not *specific* enough](http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/).

In either case, inspect the element with something like Firebug and check which CSS rules were applied to element, and if you can see the one want at the top.

Comment: It seems I cannot base64 encode the image binaries correct. I am sure I do have the correct div (Setting background:green works :) )

Comment: What tool do you use to base64 encode your images? If `background: green` works, it can still be that some `background-image` is added on top. Please try to set a `background-image` with a URL to an external image to see if an image can be applied at all.

Comment: For test reasons I used no addition divs. So there is nothing above. And adding a file for image it works.